# Remove div if all img src is null inside the div

Tags: jquery

**Html code**

```
    <div class="add_pdt_img_nc">
    <h5>Additional Images</h5>
    <img border="0" src="" alt="">
    <img border="0" src="" alt="">
    <img border="0" src="" alt="">
    <img border="0" src="" alt="">
    </div>
```

i want to remove div has class add_pdt_img_nc if all image src is null

i have tried so far

```
$(".add_pdt_img_nc img").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("src") == "") {
      $(".add_pdt_img_nc").remove();
    }
 });
```

but it remove div if first img src is null and not check if other img src has value

Comment: Use flag. Set it to false inside the loop. If it's false after iteration, do as you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var all_null = true;
$(".add_pdt_img_nc img").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("src")!= "") {
       all_null = false;
       return false; // break
    }
});
if(all_null) {
   $(".add_pdt_img_nc").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(".add_pdt_img_nc").each(function() {
    var $parent = $(this);
    if ($('img[src!=""]', this).length == 0) {
        $parent.remove();
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NNKMU/)

This checks for the existance of `img` elements within `.add_pdt_img_nc` which do have a `src` attribute set. If there are none, it removes the `div`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
$("div").each(function(){
    if ($('img[src!=""]', this).length == 0 || !$('img').attr("src")) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Note: `$(this).remove()` will remove the `img`, not the parent div.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No it targets the `div` only.